# BizTalk Pipeline IBaseMessage IPropertyContext

Tags: biztalk

When a message comes to a BizTalk pipeline , does IBaseMessage instance stands for the incoming message ?  and the property , and how to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two parts you'll be mainly interested in from the `IBaseMessage` will be the `BodParty.GetOriginalDataStream()` and the `Context` objects.  For example

```cs
Stream originalDataStream = pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();
string msgAsString;
XDocument msgAsXDoc;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(originalDataStream)
msgAsString = sr.ReadToEnd();

originalDataStream.Position = 0; // important to reset this before passing the message on!

msgAsXDoc = XDocument.Load(originalDataStream); // now you have it in an XDoc
originalDataStream.Position = 0;

XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(originalDataStream)
originalDataStream.Position = 0;

string strProperty = (string)pInMsg.Context.Read("propertyName", "http://PropertyNameSpace");

string anotherProperty = "Testing";
pInMsg.Context.Write("anotherPropertyName", "http://PropertyNamespace", anotherProperty)

pContext.ResourceTracker.Add(xr);
pContext.ResourceTracker.Add(sr);
```

etc.

A couple other notes:

- Avoid 'using' constructs, they will end up disposing of the underlying stream and causing errors
- Add any disposable objects to the context's resource tracker, which will make sure to properly call `Dispose()` on those objects when the underlying stream is ready to be disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.
`IBaseMessage` is the Message.

A clear explanation on how to create a custom pipeline component can be found here: http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2012/01/24/creating-a-custom-biztalk-2010-pipeline-componentndashpart-i.aspx

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no.

For clarity, IBaseMessage is an Interface that the actual message object's (.Net) Type implements.  It works because .Net allows Interfaces to be used as Types.

Properties are contained in the .Context collection.

Also, BizTalk IBaseMessage implementations can have multiple Parts.